# GET http://localhost:3000/salah.jpg 404 (Not Found) error on console

Tags: node.js, get, localhost, http-status-code-404, ejs

I'm new on node.js just want to access my home.ejs file from app.js file.
and it is not loading my image that is on home.ejs. just loading the contents.

my app.js code.

```
var express = require("express")

var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home.ejs");
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server Started!")
})
```

now my home.ejs code.

```
<h1>hello</h1>

<img src="salah.jpg">
```

and now file structure.

In startwithEjs folder.
node_modules
views folder
app.js file
jason files.

In views folder.
home.ejs
salah.jpg

Comment: While working with files, you may want to look into using multer.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided no way of accessing the image. Try adding something like:

```
app.get("/salah.jpg", function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
  res.end("salah.jpg");
})
```

Eventually you will need to write code that reads e.g. the images folder and provides routes to each of them. Or you could look into the [serve-static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html).

Here's a link to learn more about [how to use the response object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res).